# custom UITableViewCell item problems

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, action, textfield

I am a newbie.

I have a custom UITableViewCell with 3 items:

a UILabel
a UITextField
and a UIButton

My question is, how do I know from which cell the button was clicked or textField was edited ?

Is there a way to track them?

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is after configuring the custom cell, I save the NSIndexPath of the cell in the title of the button for the state UIControlStateApplication.

In your tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, when configuring the cell:

```
[theButton setTitle:(NSString *)indexPath forState:UIControlStateApplication];
```

Then, in your button action:

```
- (IBAction) buttonWasClicked:(UIButton *) senderButton {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;

    indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)[senderButton titleForState:UIControlStateApplication];

    NSLog(@"Sender button was clicked in cell at NSIndexPath section: %d row: %d ", [indexPath section], [indexPath row]);
}
```

I am not really happy with this way. If someone has a cleaner way to do it, I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one section you can store the `indexPath.row` in the `button.tag` and retrieve it in the action that is triggered by that button.